# Moving blocks inside tabs in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, tabs

How would I move blocks inside tab in magento2 on product view page. I would like to move inside a given tab the tier price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add below code to your custome theme. It's working.

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\default.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="product.price.tier" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.tier" group="detailed_info">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Tier Price</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: yes seems to work but my tabs are now on the top of page ans is it possible to do the same with configurable products as well

Comment: now I have twice the output I have inside tab and inside product_info how would I remove from product info?

Comment: I have update my code. now you can use for remove twice tier price.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`, add below code in `product.info.details` block.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.tier" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Tier Price</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

You need to override `catalog_product_view.xml`. Please let me know if you want any other help.

Comment: thanks I overwritten catalog_product_view.xml but this does not seems to generate a new tab

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you overwrite this file?

Comment: copy pasted the original catalog_product_view.xml from vendor to my theme  magento module and replaced the snippet  part with yours